# AppBarLayout + NestedScrollView + RecyclerView won't scroll

Tags: android

Hello I have an issue with the google support appbarLayout
my layout structure is like below :

The problem is that my recycler view won't scroll,once the nested scroll view is scrolled to the top.

I tried almost every solution, but nothing seems to work.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background_gradient_blue"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        android:padding="8dip">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    style="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/background_gradient_blue"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="250dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            style="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:contentInsetStart="72dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's the case but remove `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` from all views other than `NestedScrollView` - it's supposed to be an attribute of the views on the `AppBarLayout` level only.

Comment: already did but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved My problem

by enabling nested Scrolling

> recylcer.nestedScrollingEnabled(true)

and block the recyclerView scroll manually by reverting it, if the appBar is not collapsed

```
  mAppbarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener((appBarLayout, verticalOffset) -> {
        if (Math.abs(verticalOffset) >= appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange()) {
            //collapsed
            shouldScroll = true;
        } else {
            shouldScroll = false;
        }

    });

    mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recycler, int dx, int dy) {
            // If AppBar is not collapsed, revert the scroll.
            if (!shouldScroll) {
                if(recycler.getChildCount() >= 0){
                    recycler.scrollToPosition(0);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

And My Layout structure now looks like this :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background_gradient_blue"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/nested_scrollbar_linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingEnd="8dip"
        android:paddingLeft="8dip"
        android:paddingRight="8dip"
        android:paddingStart="8dip">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_text_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:clickable="true" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    style="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/background_gradient_blue"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="250dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            style="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:contentInsetStart="72dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add This line inside nestedScrollView tag

> android:focusableInTouchMode="true"